# prestashop md5 hash different between 2 servers (same key)

Tags: php, encryption, hash, prestashop

I have an old prestashop 1.4 that we migrated to 1.6 (2 separate servers)
we copied the customers table,
and did the usual update process (same _COOKIE_KEY_ and etc.)

but the md5 seem different

for example i do md5("previous user password") on the new server, and i get something different than what is on the old database ... what could be causing this ?

Comment: is the password salted ?

Comment: yes, using a variable _COOKIE_KEY_ , but we have it the same on both servers....and we're not able to match hashing on the new server to the old!

Comment: I don't know presta shop's encryption routing but are you sure its just a pure `md5('password')` not something like `md5(md5(password.seed).seed.now())` it could be the date format if it uses dates in password generation etc.

Comment: it has the salt added before it which is basically: cookie_key + password  , but not random (how would random work for a login anyway?) any idea or pointers/lead where to be checking? this is really puzzling

Comment: prestashop documentation would be the first point of call look at the difference in their password hashing there's been no change  to how md5() works so theoretically they should both be the same.  You can test it by doing a simple `<?php echo md5("password");?>` in a file on its own and upload that to both servers. if it spits the same out on both servers then the issue is a change in how prestashop works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is Salted - in 1.5 and newer versions there is also a SALT phrase which is added through the settings.inc.php file in Prestashop.

Comment: Some references to the change log and to the salt technique can improve your answer.